# css, display: flex в @media

Tags: html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста, я использовал `display: flex`  для выравнивания фото и текста в ряд, но для мелких размеров экрана хотелось бы сместить фото под текст, как отменить действие `flex` в `@media`, чтобы картинка снова съехала вниз? Спасибо за помощь.

```css
html,
*,
{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #222;
  font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: auto;
}


/* SECTION ABOUT */

.about {
  padding: 80px 0;
}

.about h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
}

.about h3 {
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.about .lead p {
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.about .about-content {
  display: flex;
  text-align: justify;
  font-size: 23px;
}

.about .about-text p {
  width: 10px;
}

.about .about-image img {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 100px;
  width: 95%;
  margin-top: 60px;
}

@media and (max-width: 800px) {
  .about .about-content {
    display: none;
  }
  .about .about-image img {}
}
```

```html
<section class="about">
  <div class="container">
    <h2 class="about-heading">Get to know <span class="lexl-primary">Me</span></h2>
    <div class="about-content">
      <div class="about-text>">
        <h3>A little bit <span class="text-primary">About Myself</span></h3>
        <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
          dolor in reprehenderit</p>
        <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </p>
      </div>
      <div class="about-image">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1549981832-2ba2ee913334?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=334&q=80">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

у вас ошибка в медиа запросе, лишнее and, блоку держателю .about .about-content верните дефолтное значение display: block; должно быть так:

```
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .about .about-content {
    display: block;
  }
  .about .about-image img {
    max-width: 100%;
    width: auto;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
html,
*,
{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #222;
  font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: auto;
}


/* SECTION ABOUT */

.about {
  padding: 80px 0;
}

.about h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
}

.about h3 {
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.about .lead p {
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.about .about-content {
  display: flex;
  text-align: justify;
  font-size: 23px;
}

.about .about-text p {
  width: 10px;
}

.about .about-image img {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 100px;
  width: 95%;
  margin-top: 60px;
}

@media  (max-width: 800px) {
  .about .about-content {
   flex-direction:column;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="about">
  <div class="container">
    <h2 class="about-heading">Get to know <span class="lexl-primary">Me</span></h2>
    <div class="about-content">
      <div class="about-text>">
        <h3>A little bit <span class="text-primary">About Myself</span></h3>
        <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
          dolor in reprehenderit</p>
        <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </p>
      </div>
      <div class="about-image">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1549981832-2ba2ee913334?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=334&q=80">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```